# Local code not working properly in server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have designed a page with datatable in our local server. Its working fine there but it is not working in our client side server. Even on F12 its not showing any error in console. Exactly I couldn't catch what is the error. Can anyone help me with this. How to find what error is there.

```
    <script src="dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/sweetalert.css">
    <style>
     html, body {
        max-width: 100%;
       overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    </style>

    <?php
    //include("../config/database.php");
     include('../logic/manage_logic.php');
     include "../header.php";
    if($_GET['msg']==1)
    {
    }
    ?>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['Yes']) && !empty($_POST))
    {
        $state="";
        $id=$_POST["subid"];
        $sql_qury=$mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM `recruitData` WHERE  id=?");
        $sql_qury->bind_param('i',$id);
        if($sql_qury->execute()){
           $m=1;
           header('Location:manage_access.php?msg='.$m);
        }
        else {
               echo "some thing went wrong";
        }    
        $sql_qury->close();
    }
    if(isset($_POST['No']))
    {


    }   
    ?>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
    h3, .h3 {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight : 700;
        color : #3071A9;
    } 

    </style>    
    <!--main content start-->
     <section id="main-content">
           <section class="wrapper">
           <h3><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Manage Applicants</h3>
           <span id="error"  name="error"><?php  echo $state;  ?></span>
           <!-- SIMPLE TO DO LIST -->
           <!-- BASIC FORM ELELEMNTS -->
           <div class="row mt">
           <div class="col-lg-12">
           <div class="form-panel">
           <div class="pull-right" style="margin-left:850px;margin-top:0px"><a class="fa fa-lg btn btn-success btn-sm" name="excelbtn" id="excelbtn" href="add_user_excel.php"  style="color:white">Get Excel</a> &nbsp;<a class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg btn btn-primary" href="add_user.php" style="color:white"> Add</a> <span></span></div>
            <br/>
            <br>

           <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="datatable" >

                <!--<thead style="background-color:#0E2CB0;color:white;">-->
                <thead >
                <tr>
                                  <th style="font-size:13px;">Number</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Title</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Preliminary Program</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Program</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Market</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Status</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">First Name</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Last Name</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Email Address</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Home Phone #</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Cell Phone #</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;"> Other Phone #</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Job Posting Site</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Employee Referral</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Date Applied</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Date Contacted</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Contacted By</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Contact Notes</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;width:200px">Comments</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Interview Scheduled</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Interviewing Manager</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Interview Date</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Interview Time</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Interview Outcome</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Rescheduled Date</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">New Hire Link Sent</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Start Date</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">End Date</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Production</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Uploaded Resume</th>
         <th style="font-size:13px;">Action</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
<?php 
    $details=$managedatafetch->manageSelect($mysqli);
    print_r($details);
    exit; 
   for($i=1;$i<=count($details);$i++){
      if($details[$i]['date_applied']=="0000-00-00")
      {
        $dateapplied='N/A';
      }
      else{
        $dateapplied=$details[$i]['date_applied'];
        $dateapplied=date('m/d/Y',strtotime($dateapplied));
        }
       if($details[$i]['date_contacted']=="0000-00-00")
       {
        $date_contacted='N/A';
       }
       else{
        $date_contacted=$details[$i]['date_contacted'];
        $date_contacted=date('m/d/Y',strtotime($date_contacted));
        }

       if($details[$i]['interview_date']=="0000-00-00")
       {
         $interview_date='N/A';
       }
      else{
         $interview_date=$details[$i]['interview_date'];
         $interview_date=date('m/d/Y',strtotime($interview_date));
        }
       if($details[$i]['rescheduled_date']=="0000-00-00")
      {
        $rescheduled_date='N/A';
       }
       else{
         $rescheduled_date=$details[$i]['rescheduled_date'];
         $rescheduled_date=date('m/d/Y',strtotime($rescheduled_date));
        }   
        //newHireLinkSent
       if($details[$i]['newHireLinkSent']=="0000-00-00")
       {
        $newHireLinkSent='N/A';
       }
     else{
        $newHireLinkSent=$details[$i]['newHireLinkSent'];
        $newHireLinkSent=date('m/d/Y',strtotime($newHireLinkSent));
        }   
        //startDate
    if($details[$i]['startDate']=="0000-00-00")
    {
        $startDate='N/A';
    }
    else{

        $startDate=$details[$i]['startDate'];
        $startDate=date('m/d/Y',strtotime($startDate));
        }
    if($details[$i]['endDate']=="0000-00-00")
    {
        $endDate='N/A';
    }
    else{
        $endDate=$details[$i]['endDate'];
        $endDate=date('m/d/Y',strtotime($endDate));
        }
        if($details[$i]['production']=="")
    {
        $production='N/A';
    }
    else{
        $production=$details[$i]['production'];
        }

        if($details[$i]['uploadresume']==""){
            $uploadresume="N/A";

        }
        else{
            $uploadresumearr=explode('/', $details[$i]['uploadresume']);
            $uploadresumearr1=$uploadresumearr[1];
             //$uploadresume='<a href="view_resume.php?id='.$details[$i]['id'].'" class="btn" rel="tooltip" title="View">'.$uploadresumearr1.'</a>'; 

         $uploadresume='<a href="'.$details[$i]['uploadresume'].'" >'.$uploadresumearr1.'</a>';

        }

    echo '<tr>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['number'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['title'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['preliminary_program'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['program'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['market'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['status'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['firstname'].'</td> 
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['lastname'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['email_address'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['homephone'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['cellphone'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['otherphone'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['jobPostingSite'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['employee_referral'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$dateapplied.'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$date_contacted.'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['contactedby'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['contactnotes'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;width:200px">'.$details[$i]['comments'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['interviewScheduled'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['interviewingManager'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$interview_date.'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['interview_time'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$details[$i]['interview_outcome'].'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$rescheduled_date.'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$newHireLinkSent.'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$startDate.'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$endDate.'</td>
          <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$production.'</td><td align="center" style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;">'.$uploadresume.'</td>

           <td style="font-size:13px;padding: 2px;"><a href="edit_user.php?id='.$details[$i]['id'].'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"    onclick="del('.$details[$i]['id'].');"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></button></td>


           </tr>';
        } 
?>
                </tbody>
              </table>   
      </div>
        </div><!-- col-lg-12-->         
    </div><!-- /row -->

    <!-- SORTABLE TO DO LIST -->

</section><!--/wrapper -->
</section><!-- /MAIN CONTENT -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Are  you want to Delete?</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="del">
<script>
function del(data)
 {
//alert(data);
// confirm("are you sure do you want to delete?");
//$('#del').load('delete.php?id='+id);
swal({   title: "Are you sure do you want to delete?",
  text: "Click YES to Delete!",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#8CD4F5",
  confirmButtonText: "YES",
  cancelButtonText: "NO",
  closeOnConfirm: false },
  function(){
       $.ajax({
            url: "delete.php",
            type: "post",
            data: "data="+data,
            success:function(d){
                //alert(d);
                if(d==1){
                    swal("Deleted!", "Aplicant Deleted.", "success"); 
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                else{
                    swal("Oops..", "Something Went Wrong!", "Error"); 
                }
            }
            /* cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false */
        });  
      }); 
         }
        function deleteManage(){

        }
     </script>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
       <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#datatable').dataTable({"scrollY": 300,
                     "scrollX": true}
           );
       } ); 

       //remove the inline-style 'width' from #myTable


     </script>
```

Comment: check in network tab for the response from the server

Comment: Why are you using both bootstrap based datatable and jquery datable JS at the same time? There should be one.

Comment: What's not working. The database? Does it even exist

Comment: thanks to all for the comment. We have added a column in the local database. But forgot to add it in server. Now it is working fine.. thank you

Comment: Ashwani: Thank you .. I will correct that